# New Linux user trying to setup Windows Media plugin for xmradio

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-media-player

I'm using Ubuntu 10.4 and am trying to listen to my XM Radio subscription online, however it requires windows media and Linux is obviously not listed on the system requirements page.

Is there any hope of me being able to use the server? Anything that replaces this plugin? I just started using Linux last night.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the mplayer plugin you need to add the Medibuntu Repository, where the packages are included. Follow [link text](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Medibuntu) this link to the Ubuntu Documentation. It´s described pretty good. Following this should show you how to install the needed codecs.
At the beginning of your life with ubuntu you probably need to read a lot of documentation and/or tutorials. First thing to do is bookmark [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/) site ;-) It´s the official documentation and helped me a lot.

Comment: Don´t give up yet ;-) there always is a way. You could also try installing InetExplorer into WINE. Maybe this way you will be able to use the propper codec. But this is just a suggestion I don´t know XM Radio so I can´t really rebuild your scenario for testing.